# Memory Usage of Qt Application on mobile device

Tags: qt, qtandroidextras

I was testing with simple qt quick application on android & ios device. For android,memory usage is 31 MB where as for IOS it jumps to 41 MB.

Installing through ministro  requires  active internet connection.Upon deploying,I see a lot of Qt libraries getting added,can't we remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Installed Qt libraries should only the ones used by your project. See your .pro file and remove unused Qt dependencies (`QT` flag).

For the size difference, I'm pretty sure deploying on windows will require a different memory usage. It's hard to say why one uses more memory. Every platform and compiler have there specificities and will end up with different binary sizes. There could be some compiler options to optimize by size, but speed peformance will be shown down.